# Auto populating a text box based on listbox selected value and drop down value javascript sharepoint

Tags: 2010, javascript

I have a list named "Assigning to Individual" which has a drop down 'Initial Training'

The values in the drop down are Immediate, Hire Date, Specific. There is another textbox Date

There is a listbox which contains employee name.

There is another list "Employees" which contains Employee name and Hire Date.

The scenario is when the user selects hire date in the drop down in "Assigning to Individual", and selects employee name from the listbox, then the text box should populate based on the Employees list.

I have got the code using drop down but I do not know how to get the listbox selected value. If somebody could show the changes required in my code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var currentPage = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    var result = null;
    if (currentPage.contains("Assigning to Individual")) {

        var dropdown = $("select[title = 'Initial Training']");
        var dropdownid = dropdown[0].id;
        if (dropdown.length != 0) {
            populateCourseAssignment(dropdown, dropdownid)

            $('#' + dropdownid).change(function () {
                onChangeValueDropDown(dropdownid);
            });
        }

    }

});



function populateCourseAssignment(dropdown, dropdownid) {
    //var dropdown = $("select[title = 'Course Name']");
    if (dropdown.length != 0) {
        var selectedtext = $('#' + dropdownid + ' option:selected').text();
        if (selectedtext == "Hire Date")
        result = getCourseAssignment("Initial Training", selectedtext);
        fillValuesInCourseAssignment();

    }
}

function fillValuesInCourseAssignment() {
    $("input[title = 'Date']").val(result[0].Hire_x0020_Date);
    //    $("input[title = 'Instructor Name']").val(result[0].Instructor);


}


function onChangeValueDropDown(dropdownid) {
    var currentvalue = $('#' + dropdownid + ' :selected').text();
    {
        if (currentvalue == "Hire Date")
        result = getCourse("Course_x0020_Title", currentvalue);
        fillValuesInTrainingStatus();

    }
}
function getCourseAssignment(whereColumnName, whereColumnValue) {

    var CAMLQuery = '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="' + whereColumnName + '" /><Value Type="Text">' + whereColumnValue + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>';

    // var CAMLQuery = '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="' + whereColumnName + '" /><Value Type="Text">' + whereColumnValue + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>';
    var course;
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Course Details",
        CAMLQuery: CAMLQuery,
        CAMLViewFields: "",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            //            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
            //                wizardId = getData($(this).attr("ows_" + returnColumnName));
            //            });
            course = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").SPXmlToJson({
                includeAllAttrs: true,
                removeOws: true
            });
        }
    });

    return course;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onChangeValueDropDown function change this line

```
 var currentvalue = $('#' + dropdownid + ' :selected').text();
```

To what you have in populateCourseAssignment:

```
var currentvalue = $('#' + dropdownid + ' option:selected').text();
```

Also, remove the uneccessary curly braces in the onChangeValueDropDown function. So the final will be:

```
function onChangeValueDropDown(dropdownid) {
    var currentvalue = $('#' + dropdownid + ' option:selected').text();
    if (currentvalue == "Hire Date")
    result = getCourse("Course_x0020_Title", currentvalue);
    fillValuesInTrainingStatus();
}
```

Lastly, I notice you are using SPServices. Why not use their [Cascading dropdowns function](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)?

Comment: Also, the last to lines in the function above will require curly braces if the fillValuesInTrainingStatus() function shud only be called when currentvalue is "Hire Date"

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedtext = $('#' + dropdownid).val();
```

...

```
var currentvalue = $('#' + dropdownid).val();
```

Comment: By list box I would suspect `<select><option></option></select>`, like http://jsfiddle.net/HZ3fB/

Comment: This listbox was added in sharepoint through javascript        if (currentPage.contains("Lists/Assigning to Individual/NewForm.aspx")) {
        AddNewLinkOnLookupFields("Personnel", "/Lists/Employee/NewForm.aspx", "Add New Employee");

Comment: I don't think comment is a good place to dump code, please use a pastebin such as https://gist.github.com . I can't derive anything from your dump either, only more proof that you have a `select` element, and as long as each `option` has value my code should work. You could extract the exact HTML and append it to the fiddle

Comment: Could you help me out I am not getting an idea as I am clueless about javascript, i need drop down as well , the code which you gave where should I add it